# Method Not Allowed (GET): / in django

Tags: python, django

```
from django.views.generic import View
from django.http import HttpResponse

class home(View):
  def post(self,request):
    return HttpResponse('Class based view')
```

When I tried to define above method it says Method Not Allowed (GET): /

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to View's dispatch method that you can find here:-
https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.base/View/

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Try to dispatch to the right method; if a method doesn't exist,
    # defer to the error handler. Also defer to the error handler if the
    # request method isn't on the approved list.
    if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
        handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
    else:
        handler = self.http_method_not_allowed
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

If you don't define get method in View, then dispatch will call self.http_method_not_allowed

```
def http_method_not_allowed(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    logger.warning(
        'Method Not Allowed (%s): %s', request.method, request.path,
        extra={'status_code': 405, 'request': request}
    )
    return HttpResponseNotAllowed(self._allowed_methods())
```

Here,

```
if request.method.lower() in self.http_method_names:
    handler = getattr(self, request.method.lower(), self.http_method_not_allowed)
```

In this piece of code the if condition will pass ,but when it will try to do getattr on self, request.method.lower() have get as value, so getattr will not find get method , because we have not defined it, so getattr will return http_method_not_allowed

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in base.py we define an attribute " http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace'] ",where post is present .so why django is raising this error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in base.py we define an attribute " http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put', 'patch', 'delete', 'head', 'options', 'trace'] ",where post is present .so why django is raising this error

Answer (score 9):

In your code, you have defined `post` method, but no `get` method to handle `GET` request. You can put a fix like this, for example:

```
class home(View):
    def get(self, request):
       return HttpResponse('Class based view')

    def post(self,request):
      return HttpResponse('Class based view')
```

Check here for usage of class based view: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/intro/#using-class-based-views

Comment: But when i use ur code the out put is only "get" & still i am missing the output "Class based view".Please help me to get into this matter

Comment: You can send any response you want. instead of `return HttpResponse('get')` you can put `return HttpResponse('Class based view')` in get method

Comment: Either way, I have updated my answer. you will get response  `Class based view`

Comment: But can't i get the same output by only defining post method?

Comment: you can, but then you need to make `post` request to the view. Please check here: https://www.diffen.com/difference/GET-vs-POST-HTTP-Requests about differences between GET vs POST

Comment: As i am new its seems difficult for me.And i am disturbing you again & again.it would be helpful for me if you illustrate it by an example.thanks..

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any 'get' method in your code. You defined only post method!.

In your [View](http://%20https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.base/View/) you can either define get method or call your URL with post method.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using class based views, but you didn't specify a specific class based view template, you need to declare both the post and the get.

But if you use say TemplateView, or similar, you wont.

Comment: let's be honest: I am flattened by how much info and clarity your simple comment is stating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `def post` to `def get`, see Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/#supporting-other-http-methods